# I can't add a product in Cart which price is zero in Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, cart

I have an small project of product pos system. When product price is not zero like

```
Product  Qty  Price
Mobile    1   35.00
```

the cart adds the product successfully. But when the prodcut is like

```
Product  Qty  Price
Mobile    1   0.00
```

then then the cart doesn't add the product, so how I can add the product which one's price is zero? Please suggest some option 
I'm new to cart so I'm not able to do anything, please help

Comment: Ok, so, what is happening in your system? how is your database? how is your controller? show us the part of the code receiving and showing the elements, or is going to be impossible to know what is wrong

Comment: If you making the Add cart system your own it will not do any problem.If you using any library you need to check it is using any rule for 0 price.